# How to filter virtual guests with tag A and B using Softlayer API

Tags: filter, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I added tags to my virtual guests, for example, I added tag A to VM1, and add tag A and B to VM2, I know how to get all VMs with tag A:

`https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests.json?objectMask=mask[tagReferences[tag[name]]]&objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"tagReferences":{"tag":{"name":{"operation":"*=A"}}}}}`

But I am not sure how to filter VMs with having both tag A and B. Is there a sample for reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
URL : https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"tagReferences":{"tag":{"name":{"operation":"in","options":[{"name":"data","value":["$tag1","$tag2"]}]}}}}}

Method: GET

Note: replace $tag1 and $tag2 with the tags you wish
```

Comment: Ok the issue that the object filter is not being applicated, it is probably to the REST CLient that your are using (some clients need to enconde the objectFilter) I recomend you try with Insomi or Postman clients

Comment: I just ran commands from the browser, I can get it work with one tag through running the command from the browser.

Comment: Yes, I also ran it through Chrome, I tried it with postman today, the result seems to be all VMs with OR relation of tag A and tag B, but not AND relation. Do you think if "in" for "operation" or something else is correct? Thanks.

Comment: the current result is the best you can get using objectFilter, if you want the other case you need to use your own code to fiilter the data

Comment: Ok, you mean there only can filter VMs which have tag A OR tag B, but it's impossible to filter VMs which must have both tag A AND tag B, right? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, anyway, really appreciated your help!